# Is there a way that I can watch the background videos?

Tags: rock-band-3

I have always loved the "Party Play" ability in the Guitar Hero games. I could make some characters, make a playlist, exit out of my instrument that I was playing at the time, and just sit back to watch the videos that played in the background of each song. I enjoyed it because it was like playing music on my CD player or computer but, instead, it had nice visuals that I could watch. Almost like my own personal concert.

It there a way that I could do this same thing with Rock Band 3? The background videos are beautiful and the art is fantastic but I can't watch them when I'm playing one of the songs.

Answer (score 5):

If you pick vocals, enable no fail, and turn on Performance Mode in the modifiers menu, then you should just see the background menu.

What performance mode does is take away the HUD and just shows the background video, but it still scores you which is why No Fail is necessary. I'm not sure if doing poorly on vocals will do anything to the sound of the actual vocals. You may want to turn off the crowd noises since the crowd will start booing, though.

Comment: I did what you said and it worked perfect. The vocals stay the same, even if you're failing, and I turned down the volume of the crowd so I didn't have to listen to them boo at me for failing. The visuals are simply amazing and I'm glad that I can finally admire them. Thank you so much!